# Combined JQuery menus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

As a test I'm trying to combine 2 JQuery menus. The "Slide Down Box Menu" and the "Vertical Mega Menu". But the "Vertical Mega Menu" is not working as it should. I have tried a lot, but I can't get it to work.

On the following site you can see my test: http://members.upc.nl/b.riem/.

When you hover over the list item "Projects" a sub list appears. When you hover over the item "Job Board Website" the 2nd menu (Vertical Mega Menu) should appear, but it doesn't.

On the first page there is a link to another page. On that page I did isolate the submenu under "Projects". On that page the Vertical Mega Menu is working with all the JQuery and JavaScript references still on the page.

So, on the first page there is a conflict between the 2 menus or something wrong with the CSS but I can't figure out what it is.

May I ask everyone to take a look at it and advise me what the problem could be and how I can solve it.

Thank you very much for your help and advise.

Best Regards,

Geert De Vylder

Comment: Check your console. You have an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' jquery.hoverIntent.js:113`. This happens onload, so it's not even allowing execution of your other code.

Answer (score 0):

I see that an error is being thrown from the jquery.hoverIntent.js plugin you are using. This is from line # 113 from that library that calls jquery `on()` method. But your jQuery is quite a bit older version (1.4.x) which does not have `on()` method defined. Consider upgrading your jQuery reference from google cdn as you are already using. For eg: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js for jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: Hi Ananthan,
I upgraded the jQuery reference to 1.8.3. This has as result that there is no error thrown anymore. Now you see a part of the Vertical Mega Menu when you hover over the link "Job Board Website" under Projects. But the menu does not appear completely. It's like it gets stuck inside the div element. I can't figure out how to solve this.